# The else branch in the if statement doesnt work properly (python)

Tags: python, if-statement

I expect the result will be 'Only accepted the numbers between 1 ~ 6' when I input some number like '9', but the else statement is actually ignored and get through.

main.py

```
def select_class():

  while True:
    try:
      class_number = int(input('Select number below\n (1)12:00~13:30\n (2)13:35~15:05\n (3)15:45~17:15\n (4)17:20~18:50\n (5)18:55~20:30\n (6)20:25~22:00\n---------------\n'))
      class_text = input('Leave a comment if you have\n')
  
  if re.match(r'[1-6]', class_number):
    if class_number == 1:
      class_hr, class_min = '00', '00'
      return class_hr, class_min, class_text
    elif class_number == 2:
      class_hr, class_min = '01', '35'
      return class_hr, class_min, class_text
    elif class_number == 3:
      class_hr, class_min = '03', '45'
      return class_hr, class_min, class_text
    elif class_number == 4:
      class_hr, class_min = '05', '20'
      return class_hr, class_min, class_text
    elif class_number == 5:
      class_hr, class_min = '06', '55'
      return class_hr, class_min, class_text
    elif class_number == 6:
      class_hr, class_min = '08', '30'
      return class_hr, class_min, class_text
  else:
    print('Only accepted the numbers between 1 ~ 6')
    return class_number
except ValueError:
  pass
```

terminal:

$ py main.py

Select number below

(1)12:00~13:30

(2)13:35~15:05

(3)15:45~17:15

(4)17:20~18:50

(5)18:55~20:30

(6)20:25~22:00

---

$ 9

Leave a comment if you have

$ it failed

Comment: Why do you need the first `if` with the `re.match` clause? You could have simply appended the `else` at the end of your second `if/elif` chain (and delete the first `if`).

Comment: Are you using same indentation in your actual code?. It failed is also input or some output of your code?

Comment: `class_number` is an integer, so `re.match()` ought to throw a `TypeError` exception.  Also, the indentation is incorrect as shown.  Please fix the question, so we know what code you're actually running.

Comment: Does that code ever work.  You're calling re.match on an integer (`class_number`) which should always generate a TypeError.  BTW that `if re.match...` if not needed at all, you just have to tie the else: to the end of the elifs.

Comment: 'It failed' is a comment. it maybe confused you.

Comment: At first, I didn't put `if re.match(r'[1-6]', class_number):` line. The previous code, however, didn't work as I had thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your match needs to match against a string.

```
import re
while True:
    class_number = input('Select number ...')
    class_text = input('Leave a comment if you have\n')
    if re.match(r'[1-6]', class_number):
        if class_number == '1':
            class_hr, class_min = '00', '00'
            return class_hr, class_min, class_text
        # ...
    else:
        print('Only accepted the numbers between 1 ~ 6')
```

As your code is written, your `re.match` always returns `True`, so your `else` code is never reached.

If you want to catch bad `class_number` immediately, then consider:

```
while True:
    class_number = ''
    while True:
        class_number = input('Select number: '))
        if re.match(r'[1-6]', class_number):
            break
        print('Only accept numbers 1 through 6')
    class_text = input('Leave a comment if you have: \n')
    if class_number == '1':
        class_hr, class_min = '00', '00'
    elif class_number == 2:
        class_hr, class_min = '01', '35'
    elif class_number == 3:
        class_hr, class_min = '03', '45'
    elif class_number == 4:
        class_hr, class_min = '05', '20'
    elif class_number == 5:
        class_hr, class_min = '06', '55'
    elif class_number == 6:
        class_hr, class_min = '08', '30'
    return class_hr, class_min, class_text
```

Comment: I guess `class_text = input('Leave a comment if you have\n')` should be placed somewhere else after the if statements, right?

Comment: If choosing between a string vs int representation, you should take into consideration how you want to use the data to decide.  Since we rely on regular expression here (which operates exclusively on strings) then let's pick string.  Besides, we started with string to begin with.  Casting to integer `int(input(''))` is a very common way to quickly sanity check data.  But it throws an Error which forces us int a `try` block.  It offers nothing that the regular expression check does not already do.

Comment: I will keep it mind that int(input(' ')) throws an error which forces us int a `try` block. I modified my code which you can find the answer below. It finally work but looks not smart.

Answer (score 1):

I modified the code to the one below:

```
def select_class():

while True:
 try:
  class_number = input('Select number below\n (1)12:00~13:30\n (2)13:35~15:05\n (3)15:45~17:15\n (4)17:20~18:50\n (5)18:55~20:30\n (6)20:25~22:00\n---------------\n')

  if int(class_number) == 1:
    class_hr, class_min = '00', '00'
    class_text = input('Leave a comment if you have\n')
    return class_hr, class_min, class_text
  elif int(class_number) == 2:
    class_hr, class_min = '01', '35'
    class_text = input('Leave a comment if you have\n')
    return class_hr, class_min, class_text
  elif int(class_number) == 3:
    class_hr, class_min = '03', '45'
    class_text = input('Leave a comment if you have\n')
    return class_hr, class_min, class_text
  elif int(class_number) == 4:
    class_hr, class_min = '05', '20'
    class_text = input('Leave a comment if you have\n')
    return class_hr, class_min, class_text
  elif int(class_number) == 5:
    class_hr, class_min = '06', '55'
    class_text = input('Leave a comment if you have\n')
    return class_hr, class_min, class_text
  elif int(class_number) == 6:
    class_hr, class_min = '08', '30'
    class_text = input('Leave a comment if you have\n')
    return class_hr, class_min, class_text
  else:
    print('Only accepted the numbers between 1 ~ 6')
    continue
except ValueError:
  pass
```

It works but still looks redundant somewhat.

Comment: This is actually a bad answer: you should cast `int` once,  you should narrow `try` block, you duplicate two lines of code in all 6 of your checks, and you have entangled `class_number` verification with `class_text` verification.  This is a code maintainer's nightmare.

Comment: This is pretty much that you pointed out. I couldn't hit on a right code when there are a number of conditional branches. I read your answer once again and understood how to use a while statement properly for now.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for re.match(pattern, string)

So the code re.match(r'[1-6]', class_number) is always throwing an exception.

Change your code to below

class_number = input(
'Select number below\n (1)12:00~13:30\n (2)13:35~15:05\n (3)15:45~17:15\n (4)17:20~18:50\n (5)18:55~20:30\n (6)20:25~22:00\n---------------\n')
class_text = input('Leave a comment if you have\n')

========

9
Leave a comment if you have
343
<class 'str'>
Only accepted the numbers between 1 ~ 6